# Kibana anonymous access with docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elastic-stack

**Problem description**

I am trying to get anonymous access setup on Kibana with docker so I can share embedded and link to dashboards I created. I am using version 7.17.17 and Docker-compose to get my Elastic/Kibana stack going, however, I'm having troubles getting this access working.

I have read the links from the docs but they don't seem to do the trick for me. The Kibana portion of the `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
kib01:
  image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.17.17
  container_name: kib01
  ports:
    -5601:5601
  environment:
    SERVER_BASEPATH: /whatever
    ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: user
    ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: password
  volumes:
    - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
  networks:
    - elastic
```

And here's what my `kibana.yml` looks like:

```
xpack.security.authc.providers:
  basic.basic1:
    order: 0
  anonymous.anonymous1:
    order: 1
    username: "guest_user"
    password: "guest_pass"
```

**Issues that occur**

If I run docker-compose like this I can't access my Kibana server at http://url/whatever, it doesn't redirect to Kibana. If I comment the "volumes" portion of the docker-compose it redirects just fine when I access it at `http://url/whatever`. So I can't even check if the anonymous login works or not.

**Things I've tried**

Setting up the `kibana.yml` variables inside the docker-compose like so:

```
XPACK_SECURITY_AUTHC_PROVIDERS_BASIC_BASIC1_ORDER: 0
XPACK_SECURITY_AUTHC_PROVIDERS_ANONYMOUS_ANONYMOUS1_ORDER: 1
XPACK_SECURITY_AUTHC_PROVIDERS_ANONYMOUS_ANONYMOUS1_USERNAME: "guest_user"
XPACK_SECURITY_AUTHC_PROVIDERS_ANONYMOUS_ANONYMOUS1_PASSWORD: "guest_pass"
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything.

I've also tried to write the environment variables over to the `kibana.yml` but I get the same results as having the "volumes" in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I can't access the Kibana server over at `http://url/whatever`.

I have also tried to set the environment variable

```
XPACK_SECURITY_SAMESITECOOKIES: None
```

That didn't solve it either.

The `kibana.yml` file is copying over just fine to the Docker VM since I accessed it and checked it was doing so just fine.

I'm kinda at a loss of what to do now so hoping I can get some help.

Comment: You need to insert a space after the `-` in your ports specification: `- 5601:5601` otherwise that's not a valid YAML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled around with the two YAML files to get something that would run.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.17.17
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVER_BASEPATH: /whatever
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: user
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    networks:
      - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    name: elastic-network
```

`kibana.yml`:

```
xpack.security.authc.providers:
  basic.basic1:
    order: 0
  anonymous.anonymous1:
    order: 1
    credentials:
      username: "anonymous_user"
      password: "your_password"
```

With that setup I can successfully bring up the Docker Compose stack, but when I connect to http://127.0.0.1:5601/ something is clearly not right.

[image]

Looking at the logs revealed the problem. Without a `kibana.yml` configuration file:

```
{"message":"http server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601"}
```

and with the configuration file:

```
{"message":"http server running at http://localhost:5601"}
```

Aha! This is important because `0.0.0.0` is what you want, not `localhost`. To fix this we can add `server.host` to our `kibana.yml`.

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.security.authc.providers:
  basic.basic1:
    order: 0
  anonymous.anonymous1:
    order: 1
    credentials:
      username: "anonymous_user"
      password: "your_password"
```

And with that at least you can access Kibana without error:

[image]

Now you just need to get everything (ElasticSearch etc.) hooked up so that the Kibana server is ready to accept requests.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but that was it! The VM that I was using didn't allow me to scroll up so I never managed to spot that difference. You're a life saver !